# Entity Framework Seed Data not running

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, seeding

Running Entity Framework 6.1 in a Web API application. I have my DatabaseContext setup and when I run Update-Database from the package manager console, the database creates and seeds correctly.

However, if I delete or manually create the database and then run the application, entity framework will create the tables in the database, but the seed methods to populate the data are not run. Anyone have any idea why the seed data would not be running? Code is below.

```
    namespace MyProject.API.DBMigrations
{
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;
    using MyProject.API.Infrastructure;
    using MyProject.Models.Business_Models;
    using MyProject.Models.Domain_Models;
    using MyProject.Models.Models;

    internal sealed class DatabaseConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyProject.API.Infrastructure.ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public DatabaseConfiguration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
            MigrationsDirectory = @"DBMigrations";
        }

        protected override void Seed(MyProject.API.Infrastructure.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.
            DatabaseSeeder.SeedSecurity(context);
            DatabaseSeeder.SeedBusiness(context);

            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }

    public class MyProjectDBInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyProject.API.Infrastructure.ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        // This Seed method is run when database is initialized if it is created if none exists
        protected override void Seed(MyProject.API.Infrastructure.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            DatabaseSeeder.SeedBusiness(context);
            DatabaseSeeder.SeedSecurity(context);

            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }

    public static class DatabaseSeeder
    {
        public static void SeedSecurity(MyProject.API.Infrastructure.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
           //SEED Data added here (redacted for brevity)
        }

        public static void SeedBusiness(MyProject.API.Infrastructure.ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
      //SEED Data added here (redacted for brevity)
    }
    }
}
```

Here is part of my db context where I set the initializers. I've even tried setting the initializer in global.asax, but that didn't help.

```
    namespace MyProject.API.Infrastructure
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new MyProjectDBInitializer());
        }

        // no change: this static ctor called the first time this type is referenced
        static ApplicationDbContext() {
            System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new MyProjectDBInitializer());
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //Fluent api code here
            // Add foreign key constraint here or else nullable doesn't work when EF does savechanges
            modelBuilder.Entity<GiftCardTransaction>().Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like that should work, but perhaps the issue is related to mixing the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges initializer with migrations? DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges is meant for early development without migrations, then once you have a base of data you want to keep switch the initializer to MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion and use migrations. If you stick with DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges , I would see if debugger is hitting the code as expected. http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/

Comment: I tried all the different base initializers, but let me try stepping through like you suggested and see if it's getting it. I thought when I tried that it forced me to stop debugging but maybe it was something else.